# Why sample complexity must be polynomial for PAC learning?

Tags: definition, pac-learning

I'm reading up on Probably Approximately Correct (PAC) learning and most sources require that the sample complexity must be polynomial in $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\frac{1}{\delta}$, where ${\epsilon}$ and ${\delta}$ are error rate and failure rate, respectively.

I have also found [lecture notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Edanroth/Teaching/CS446-17/LectureNotesNew/colt/main.pdf) that states there are two limitations to PAC:

> - Polynomial sample complexity, which is also called information    theoretic constraint, governs if there is enough information in the sample to distinguish a hypothesis $h$ that approximate $f$
> - Polynomial    time complexity, also called computational complexity, which tells if    there is an efficient algorithm that can process the
>   sample and    produce a good hypothesis $h$

$f$ is a concept from some concept class $C$.

While it is somewhat usefull, I don't understand where this requirement comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the original motivation of "A Theory of the Learnable" [Valliant (1984)](http://web.mit.edu/6.435/www/Valiant84.pdf).

The idea is that people appear to be able to learn concepts from a reasonable number of examples, so that learning from a reasonable number of examples should be a process that can be automated. It's certainly plausible that learning more complicated classes will take longer, and learning with fewer errors will take longer. And it's traditional in computer science to defined 'reasonable' in terms of polynomial growth.

So, if you consider PAC-learning as a model for how learning could really happen, it makes sense to have polynomial complexity and error bounds. And, in addition, it turns out to be a 'nice' class with other interesting properties.